# Are VB.NET and C#.NET projects created from Microsoft Visual Studio "Open Source" safe?

Tags: c#, open-source, visual-studio, vb.net

I'm developing software in VB.NET and C#.NET and planning to release their source codes as fully open source. Are these projects "open-source" safe?

**My doubts are:**

1. VB.NET and C#.NET are using the .NET framework which is not open source.
2. The source codes depends on the compiler and the IDE, although there's 100% open source and compatible alternatives provided, it is confirmed to be buggy and incompatible with my project.
3. My projects were using the Jet 4.0 OLE DB, which is not open source either.
4. Files like .Designer.vb, Microsoft ResX Schema, the Solution file, or the .vbproj etc that are generated by the Visual Studio

Maybe I didn't have enough knowledge on open-source in the field where the codes released can be mixed with non open-source, or the codes can be released as open source even though developed and generated on a non open-source IDE.

Am I still eligible to hold the "open-source project" title? Can the codes be released as open-source? If so, what kind of open source license that are compatible based on the criteria above?

Comment: "Open source" is not a title or a certification.  Open source simply means the ability to read the source code.  It's more about the *software license,* which dictates the terms by which the source can be used or distributed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the clearance. open source is not about title, what about the compatibility with open source licenses? Thanks

Comment: What about it?  There are several kinds of software licenses.  Some of them require that you provide *all* of the source, not just *some* of it.  Those that do require you to open all of the source sometimes exempt system components like the OS.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are projects like this eligible for using Apache License version 2.0? what else that are compatible, I need to select an open source license which is fully compatible with projects like this. thanks.

Comment: You pick a license based on the features that you want your license to have.  Apache is a fairly permissive license; it allows anyone to do pretty much anything they want with your code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see. I can tolerate modifications as long as they state what they have done with the codes. In other means, I still don't understand about how codes that are generated by a proprietary IDE and includes proprietary components can be released as fully open source.

Comment: Its about the same as how you can sell a house that you made with tools you bought from stores, designed by other people. You aren't giving away the concept of the tools, only the result/method of using them. Though of course the AGPL license would make that unlawful, if you like. Even then, only point 3 would be an issue.

Comment: @FarizLuqman: The IDE code is not open source, but *the code that you write in an IDE belong to you.*  It is your work, and you can license it however you please.

Comment: @Magus the point 3. Assuming that the component for connecting to database isn't being included. And the database *file is compatible with Open Office Base. should it still be an issue?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Bingo! I've been licensing the whole codes including the IDE codes, which I should not.

Comment: Unless you're trying to license the source code of visual studio itself, you're fine. Generated code is safe. You can sell paper even if it was printed on by an HP printer, without asking HP. If you're just using open formats, there is of course no problem, but some licenses like GPL don't even allow you to call compiled proprietary code.

Comment: @Magus yes. it is crystal clear now. sadly you're answering on the comments area where I can't accept it as an answer to show it on the community. lol

Comment: @Magus: that's not strictly true, otherwise GPL software would be forbidden on Windows.

Comment: @whatsisname: LGPL exists because static linking of GPL and proprietary code wasn't possible. Dynamic linking is always fine, as far as I know, until you start reaching the AGPL level. I do understand that my previous statement is general and only kind of true, but it gets the point across. Besides, FOSS would *love* GPL to be incompatible with Windows if they could get away with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your code is your own.

Generated code is also your code. While Microsoft may have built the mechanism to output it, it is no more owned by them than a brochure your company prints is owned by HP. Using an IDE to write your code does not make the IDE developers own it.

Note, however, that your code is, more accurately, your employer's if you create it on the job.

### On Licensing

Only a lawyer can truly explain exactly what is covered or not in a specific license, but the matters mentioned in your question aren't too difficult.

There are various kinds of licenses. Anything stricter than LGPL will not allow you to reference compiled assemblies that are not under the same (or compatible) license. Anything less, and you can. You may not be able to package proprietary software with your own, depending on the license, but you could still use it.

That should be everything you need to do the rest of the research into the license you want. Mostly, read the terms. They tell you exactly what's allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. I now have clearer image to advance on Open Source lane. Thank you